# jQuery wrap element inside a <li> and then appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, resize

I am trying when wrap two `<a>` elements inside a `<li>` then to move them to another `div`. Now everytime when resize the window, and two new empty `<li>` are added. How to fix it ?

```
$(document).ready(appendBtns);
$(window).resize(appendBtns);

function appendBtns() {
    if($(window).innerWidth() < 768) {
       $('.btn').wrap('<li>').parent().appendTo('.main-nav ul')
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a flag somewhere to indicate that you have already wrapped and added them …? (Store some .data() on an element, set a class on html/body to hold this information, …)

Comment: Or make sure those two links are always there (duplicate, if necessary, if you need them elsewhere when on desktop) - and let the CSS media queries take care of _showing/hiding_ whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**if your .main-nav ul has no other li elements in it** just empty it before you add as I did as follows:

```
$(document).ready(appendBtns);
$(window).resize(appendBtns);

function appendBtns() {
    if($(window).innerWidth() < 768) {
       $('.main-nav ul').html(''); //add this line
       $('.btn').wrap('<li>').parent().appendTo('.main-nav ul')
    }
}
```

**Note: This is the use case if your UL doen't has no other li's except the ones you are appending**

Answer (score 0):

Every time you resize your window, you create two new li.  I would change your code to so it checks if the buttons have already been moved:

```js
$(document).ready(appendBtns);
$(window).resize(appendBtns);

var $navUl = $('.main-nav ul'); // do your selector here and cache in var for better performance
var $buttons = $('.btn');

function appendBtns() {
  if ($(window).innerWidth() < 768 && !$buttons.closest('.main-nav').length) { // check to see if buttons have already been moved

    $navUl.append($buttons.wrap('<li></li>').parent())
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul></ul>
</nav>
<a href="#" class="btn">test</a>
<a href="#" class="btn">test 1</a>
```